# Ping output to HTML Page not Wrapping Text

Tags: python, html, templates, ping

How do I get the output to look like it does in the HTML? It doesn't return at each line or keep and of the formatting, it just prints it out as one Giant block of text.

But it wraps if I put it at a default length but that does not work for pings as each row is of varrying sizes.

Python code to generate Ping:

```
ping = 'ping -w 500 ' + 'IP'

gatewayping = os.popen(ping).read()
```

The output is then plugged into a premade HTML Template I made:

```
                <h3>Ping to ISP Gateway:</h3>
                <p>{{link_ping_gateway}} </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
            </div>
        </div>
''')


ipsla_html = ipsla_template.render(
     link_name = local_ipsla_urllist,
     link_ping_gateway = gatewayping
)
```

HTML Code:

```
                    ...
                    <h3>Ping to ISP Gateway:</h3>
                    <p>
Pinging 10.xxx.xxx.xxx with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.xxx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time=45ms TTL=248
Reply from 10.xxx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time=44ms TTL=248
Reply from 10.xxx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time=45ms TTL=248
Reply from 10.xxx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time=45ms TTL=248

Ping statistics for 10.xxx.xxx.xxx:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 44ms, Maximum = 45ms, Average = 44ms
 </p>
                </div>
```

Output

```
Ping to ISP Gateway:
Pinging 10.xxx.xxx.xxx with 32 bytes of data: Reply from 10.xxx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time=45ms TTL=248 Reply from 10.xxx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time=44ms TTL=248 Reply from 10.xxx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time=45ms TTL=248 Reply from 10.xxx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time=45ms TTL=248 Ping statistics for 10.xxx.xxx.xxx: Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss), Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds: Minimum = 44ms, Maximum = 45ms, Average = 44ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your output to appear the same as it does on a terminal, either use `pre` tags, or apply a CSS style like `white-space: pre` (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp).